# TYPO3 9 - site definition on subpage

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i have the following page tree:

```
root (1)
   Home (2)
     firstpage (3)
     secondpage (4)
```

etc. Home is my startpage, which i made to Root Page in Tab Behavior.

I defined a site for Home [ID:2] (Domain, language etc) but not for root (1). root is my container page for templates - this should become a multi domain setup.

But this setup seems not to work anymore. The site configuration demands a configuration for root [ID 1] and in the frontend I get a "page not found" error.

When i change my setup and define a site configuration for root [ID:1] instead of Home [ID:2] all works as expected. Is this approach with a root page for template inheritance not possible anymore in TYPO3 9? Or do i miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you also added a "Site configuration" ? (Module Site management > Sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that site configuration can only be applied to a page on the root level.

Instead of inheriting templates, you can just include them where needed.

```
templates (5)
Home (2) (include template here from 5)
  firstpage (3)
  secondpage (4)

nextsite(6) (include template here from 5)
  firstpage (7)
```